# Anyone know of solutions for Windows 1903 breaking resume from sleep with bluetooth dongle?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, sleep, power, windows-10-v1903

Since being upgraded to 1903, when my computer resume from sleep the screen remains off and I need to hard reset, losing my work.

Through a lot of trial and error I have isolated this to the use of a bluetooth dongle for my bluetooth keyboard. Unplugging the dongle solves the problem.

I thought it was the dongle's fault so purchased another one ([first one was EkoBuy "V8" chipset](https://www.ekobuy.com/support/downloads/ekobuy-usb-bluetooth-v4-0-adapter-dongle-pc-windows-10-8-7-xp-in-retail-package), second one was much more compatible [Plugable "Broadcom" chipset](https://plugable.com/products/usb-bt4le/)) - both of these should work with Windows 10 out of the box - I also updated the driver to the alternatives on the respective company websites but the problem occurs in all cases.

My other drivers/bios are all up to date and fairly modern hardware (Asus B360M-A motherboard, i5-8400 cpu, NVidia 1050ti)

If I disable the "Power" service, then I can manually put the computer to sleep and resume works fine - however this is not ideal as I have to remember to do it!

Hoping someone knows of a solution to this or that Microsoft are listening (I did submit feedback to their hub too) as this is really quite a pain!

Comment: Microsoft doesn’t follow issues reported on Super User.  I have never seen anyone from Microsoft answer a question here at Super User.

Comment: I would start by ignoring all other suggestions and make sure you have the most recent [Intel B360](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28182/Chipset-INF-Utility?product=133332) chipset driver.  Most power issues like you described are caused by chipset drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound - yep I am totally up to date via the Asus site - actually when I tried to install the version from your link it told me it was a downgrade :) thanks for the advice anyhow

Comment: Just as a sanity check I did the downgrade to the version on Intel's site but still no cigar. Also notice that occasionally it does come back from sleep - not sure exactly the conditions of this... already spent hours trying to diagnose this so probably won't spend much more time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I did a fresh reinstall and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Given all you have done (I assume All Drivers means you also updated the Power Driver), I suggest you upgrade the Bluetooth dongle to a newer model. That seems most likely at this point.

Comment: The author already purchased different Bluetooth module and it didn’t solve the problem